# Media Query - Change <h1> content?

Tags: html, css, header, nav

Im trying to create a responsive design here through media queries - so far it's been going pretty well, although i just hit a wall!
I have a h1 in my header which is pretty long, so when the screen gets small enough, it won't fit in - and ruins the responsive idea.

What i am asking is, is it possible to change the content in my h1 when the gets - lets say 500px wide? (example)

Right now my h1 is "CARSTEN ANDERSEN", and i would like it to change to "CARSTEN" at 500px.

Thanks in advance

Comment: add code or js fiddle for exact answer...

Comment: Are you 100% set on not resizing the text or having it break onto 2 lines? You might not necessarily have to resort to hiding information from smaller resolutions.

Comment: Developerrr - it wasn't really a specific question for my code, more like a general one. And i got the answer.

Edmund Reep - Well not 100% sure about breaking into 2 lines, resizing is out of question though. In this case it doesn't hide anything too important, so i think i will stick with hiding it =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<h1>Carsten <span class="hide-when-narrow">Andersen</span></h1>
<style>
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .hide-when-narrow {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
```

Since this is a question of content, it should be handled in the markup.

Comment: Just what i was looking for. Thank you! Pretty easy!

Answer (score 1):

You could hide the excess words/letters by using `max-width` with `overflow: hidden` (use `white-space: nowrap` to force one line):

```css
h1 { border:1px solid red; }

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  h1 { max-width: 158px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; }
}
```

```html
<h1>CARSTEN ANDERSEN</h1>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/cs5ttm7s/

Comment: Then it would say "CARSTEN ANDE".
Good idea though!

Comment: Right. you will have to change the max-width value to the size of the first word. Admittedly not the most straightforward method but just another way to achieve your goal :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the content property

```css
h1:before {
  content: 'CARSTEN ANDERSEN';
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  h1:before {
    content: 'CARSTEN';
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>

</h1>
```

Something like this?

Comment: I thought of this but it's not optimal for SEO or Web Accessibility. Maybe if the full text was wrapped in a span and then hidden with a media query would work. (hide span then add text through pesudo element content)

Comment: Thank you for the idea - i think i will go with Boldewyn's solution!

Comment: Yeah this one is right. But using the width was not the right solution i guess since the width may someday change! Anyway thanks for improving the fiddle! I had something to learn here too!